# node.js POST exercise displays raw HTML, not the Form

Tags: html, forms, node.js, post

I'm a node.js beginner.  and following the exercises in Manuel K's "Node Beginner" book.

And successfully run the exercises until the first POST exercise on p. 50.

Therefore this is more of a browser configuration question:

the first POST exercise, to display a form, is displaying the raw HTML.  happens in Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Sea Monkey..   I've searched the web for "raw HTML code", found some answers, but all point at cookies and domains.  remember, the server is at:

```
 http://localhost:8888
```

i've pasted the code from the book, so I'm fairly certain the "Content-Type" stuff is ok, it worked thru the "exec" exercise.

i've also checked the "similar questions" here and will continue to browse, but ...

here's the relevant fragment:

```
function start(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

    var body = '<html>'+
        '<head>'+
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; '+
        'charset=UTF-8" />'+
        '</head>\n'+
        '<body>\n\t'+
        '<form action="/upload" method="post">\n\t'+
        '<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>\n\t'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Submit text" />\n'+
        '</form>'+
        '</body>'+
        '</html>';

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(body);
        response.end();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `Content-Type` on your response:

`response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});` should be `response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});`

You are declaring the proper DOCTYPE in you response body, but the `Content-Type` header is what the browser is going to use to figure out how to display the response.

Comment: Glad to help : ) The Node Beginner book is where I cut my teeth on Node as well. Good luck!